# Configure CMake to show include directory in QT Creator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, sfml

I'm trying to figure out how SFML's CMake configuration shows the `<SFML/*>` `include` directory in a project folder.

[image: project tree]

My test project has `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` but the `include` folder does not appear in the project structure like SFML's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder will show up if you have added any source files from within that directory (or a subdirectory below it) to any target in the project. Since you are talking about headers, you can simply add the header files as sources to an existing target. CMake will just ignore them as far as the building of that target is concerned, but it will then add those headers to the project's list of files. I've also seen people add a static library target with nothing but headers listed just so those headers show up in the project view. A bit hacky in my opinion, but it gets the job done.